# pass PHP Variable to JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

The approach used in this question is WRONG. As mentioned in comments, PHP is server side processing and JS is client side processing (browser). The 2 should not be mixed.

Seems like a trivial problem with an apparently easy solution. I have a PHP file which is loaded via  a post. In this document I can retrieve the posted value as such:

```
$userid = $_POST["userid"];
```

Then in my Javascript in `$(document).ready(function()` I am trying to assign the post value to Javascript variable as such :

```
var jsvariable = <?php echo($_POST["userid"])?>;
```

Keep geeting either **variable undefined** in js error or  syntax error, **unexpected T_VARIABLE** error inPHP.

Please advise how I can successful retrieve this value.

Comment: Two typical approaches: 1. you create the javascript code in a dynamic manner by php, that way you can code a php variable value into the javascript code, or 2. you store the php variable value in some hidden html tag or property and read it with javascript.

Comment: Is the javascript in a `.js` file or part of a `.php` file? In a `.js` file it probably does not get parsed.

Comment: @arkascha  ...coyld u plz help me understand why this is?

Comment: The javascript is evaluated on the client side. Only. On the client side there is no php, that is server side. You cannot mix the two sides like that, one runs _after_ the other. This will only work if you create that javascript code by means of php, not as a static file. Which would be option 1. of what I wrote above.

Answer (score 2):

There are two approaches for this:

First if your js is present inside a php file then in that case.

```
var jsvariable = "<?php echo $_POST["userid"]; ?>";
```

And if your js is present in a .js file then in that case.

```
var jsvariable2 = "<?php echo $_POST["userid"]; ?>";
```

and below this line. Call the js file.

```
<script src="whatever.js" type="text/javascript">
```

And inside the js assign the above created variable to it:

```
var jsvariable = jsvariable2;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I recommend this one. I also did the same thing

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var jsvariable = <?php echo('\"'.$_POST["userid"].'\"')?>;
```

instead

```
var jsvariable = <?php echo($_POST["userid"])?>;
```

if userid="ehdrbs0318" in php,
in javascript

```
var jsvariable = ehdrbs0318;
```

you have to assign string like

```
var jsvariable = "ehdrbs0318";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `json_encode`:

```
var jsvariable = <?php echo json_encode($_POST["userid"]) ?>;
```

This will add the necessary quotes if the PHP variable is a string, but will also respond well to non-string values.

As a side note: you can use the PHP short-cut notation to output values:

```
var jsvariable = <?= json_encode($_POST["userid"]) ?>;
```

#### PHP error

The error `unexpected T_VARIABLE` in PHP you (sometimes) get, is unrelated to the code you have provided: it is a simple syntax error, and it means the parser found a variable name at an unexpected place. Maybe you forgot to end the previous statement with a semicolon, or maybe you forgot a closing parenthesis or bracket....